# WPF Validation Rule on ComboBox calling the Setter of binded propery twice

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="TipoVisitante" ItemsSource="{Binding TiposVisitante}" SelectedValue="{Binding TipoVisitante}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
   <ComboBox.Text>
      <Binding Path="TipoVisitante" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <validations:SimpleIsRequiredValidation/>
         </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
   </ComboBox.Text>
</ComboBox>
```

This ComboBox is binded to the TipoVisitante property from the ViewModel. The TipoVisitante variable looks like this:

```
private string _TipoVisitante;
public string TipoVisitante {
  get =>_TipoVisitante;
  set {
    if (ValidarTipoVisita(value) == true) {
      _TipoVisitante = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("YA EXISTE UNA VISITA ÍNTIMA ACTIVA", "VISITA INTIMA ACTIVA", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
      _TipoVisitante = null;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

When TipoVisitante is set, I want to check if the value is valid using a method that return true or false depending on which the value is valid or not. If the the values isn't valid, I show a message saying that the value is not valid. The problem is, because of the validation on rule on the ComboBox, the set property of the TipoVisitante variable is called twice, and the error message is shown twice. The Validation Rule of the ComboBox looks like this:

```
public class SimpleIsRequiredValidation: ValidationRule {
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value ? .ToString())) 
       return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    else 
       return new ValidationResult(false, null);
  }
}
```

The validation rule checks if the user has selected some value of the combobox, checking if the text is null or a empty string. Also in my code behind I have this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TipoVisitante.Text)) 
     TipoVisitante.Text = "";
}
```

This method is the Click property of a button. When the button is click, I check if the user hasn't selected some value of the ComboBox I set the text to empty string to trigger the validation and show the red border in the ComboBox.

How can I avoid the setter of the binded variable TipoVisitante to be called twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add extra property that check was it called once then use it to block call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was change the validation from ComboBox.Text to ComboBox.SelectedValue. After that in the button Click action, change `TipoVisitante.Text = ""` to `TipoVisitante.SelectedValue = null`. Doing that it worked fine.